# What Does Unicode 8.0 Mean For Chinese?

Tags: characters

Was reading [Unicode 8.0 Brings 7,716 New Characters Including 36 New Emoji and 5 Skin Modifiers](http://m.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=49915) on iClarified, the article also mentioned:

> 5,771 new ideographs for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean

- What Does Unicode 8.0 Mean For Chinese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I think I just wrap this up in a proper answer instead of some comments with links.

Basically, there are [two major changes](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/):

- 9 new characters were added to the  CJK Unified Ideographs block.
- A new block called 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E' with 5762 ideographs was added to Unicode. You can [find these here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-8.0/U80-2B820.pdf) (.pdf file).

Characters from the first page of the file:
[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E_.28projected.29), in the early stages of the new standard version, 
*CJK-E was originally intended to include another 16,000+ characters not present in CJK-C. However, in May 2007 the Republic of China (Taiwan) withdrew 6,545 personal name usage characters deemed no longer in use,in May 2013 China withdrew 6 characters, and many others were later withdrawn or moved to CJK-F (projected), so the current version includes 5,762 new characters. CJK-E including 5,762 Han characters will be new in Unicode 8.0.*

Here's a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E) that will document these, but most browsers fail to display the characters yet.

---

UPDATE: [Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/) supports CJK Ext. E. Download the font [from here](http://iij.dl.sourceforge.jp/hanazono-font/62072/hanazono-20141012.zip).